# Foreman smart-proxy fails to start on Windows (Server 2012 R2)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, foreman

I recently discovered ***Foreman*** and installed a 1.9.1 release to help me manage and provision my servers.

The *foreman* server is installed on the same machine of my puppet server. Now, I want to use a smart-proxy on a windows hosts to help me manage MS DHCP and DNS server.

I followed the setup procedure on the [Foreman website](http://www.theforeman.org/manuals/1.9/index.html#4.3.4DHCP) but when I finally start the smart-proxy with

```
ruby bin\smart-proxy
```

I got the following error :

```
C:\smart-proxy>ruby bin\smart-proxy
[2015-09-22 09:03:53] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-09-22 09:03:53] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]
[2015-09-22 09:03:53] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-09-22 09:03:53] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:75:in `getaddrinfo': getaddrinfo: Unknown host.  (SocketError)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:75:in `create_listeners'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/ssl.rb:88:in `listen'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:70:in `initialize'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:45:in `initialize'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:11:in `new'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:11:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
    from C:/smart-proxy/lib/smart_proxy.rb:137:in `block in launch'
```

The DNS resolution is OK for the smart-proxy server and the puppet/foreman server.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `:bind_host` in `config/settings.yml`.  The default is `*` which is intended to bind to all interfaces, but I think under Windows you may need to set it to `0.0.0.0` instead.

If that doesn't work, try using an IP address or hostname of the server.

Comment: I try to set `:bind_host:` to 0.0.0.0 -> same error. It's the same if I specify the IP address of the host.

Comment: I replaced `:bind_host: 0.0.0.0` with `:bind_host: '0.0.0.0'` and it solved the problem ! Thanks for your help

Comment: Thankyou for this - the Foreman documentation seems totally geared at Linux with no footnotes or anything for running on Windows. I was just about to ask a question on Server Fault when I found your answer.